# Improperly Healed Broken Bones

Tags: past-participles

https://www.pennstatehealth.org/services-treatments/malunion-fractures

> Improperly Healed Broken Bones

Does it really make sense?
I think it's contradictory because bones can't be healed and broken at the same time.

Comment: A wound or injury can be healed. The black eye my mother gave me is now healed.

Comment: Think about this: unless you say broken bones, you'd get: improperly healed bones. Which in context might fly but still we'd say: broken bones more generally. His broken bones did not heal. You can't leave out broken there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it makes sense. Language is not always completely logical.

We can obviously say "My leg was broken but it has healed".

But we can also say "My broken leg has healed", where we mean that the leg was broken but isn't any more.

And further, we can talk about "my fully healed broken leg", in the same way.

Michael has answered the bit about "improperly healed", but I don't think that that was what you were primarily asking about.